# Citation Inconsistency

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber

I am having a strange issue in my bibliography where all but one entry correctly sets the DOI hyperlink.

I am attaching an image which shows the problem entry alongside a correct entry. All entries besides the top example properly hides the DOI. The DOI before the year should not be there.

I am also including the *.bib. Am I doing something wrong in the bibliography file? I use biblatex format with the biber backend. The style is AIP (Phys). The compiler is lualatex.

[image]

```
@article{AlvarezJ2012,
  author = {Álvarez{-}Idaboy, J. and Galván, Marcelo and Vela, Alberto and Zicovich{-}Wilson, Claudio and Valencia, Diego and Peña, Laura and García{-}Cruz, Isidoro},
  title = {Reaction Mechanism of Hydrogenation and Direct Desulfurization Routes of Di\-ben\-zo\-thi\-o\-phene{-}Like Compounds: {A} Density Functional Theory Study},
  journal = {International Journal of Quantum Chemistry},
  volume = {112},
  date = {2012-11-15},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.24242},
  doi = {10.1002/qua.24242}
}
```

```
@article{BhadraBiswaNath2019,
  author = {Bhadra, Biswa Nath and Jhung, Sung Hwa},
  publisher = {Elsevier B.V},
  title = {Oxidative Desulfurization and Denitrogenation of Fuels Using Metal-Organic Framework-Based/-Derived Catalysts},
  journal = {Applied catalysis. B, Environmental},
  volume = {259},
  pages = {118021},
  date = {2019},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apcatb.2019.118021},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apcatb.2019.118021},
  issn = {0926-3373}
}
```

Comment: you should always show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is. Note that latex does not hyphenate words containing `-`

Comment: Please, provide a Minimal Working Example (MWE). It is much easier to help you.

Comment: I'm not aware of a `biblatex` style called "AIP" or similar, so a complete example document would really help me understand which style you are using.

Comment: @moewe in my answer below I guessed that it is [biblatex-phys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-phys) by Joseph Wright.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I put in parenthesis the biblatex name of phys. @Marijn posted a correct solution. I apologise for the lack of an MWE, I will keep in mind for the future to include one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys/biblatex-phys.pdf) of the Biblatex AIP style mentions the following (page 1, emphasis mine):

> The standard style options `doi`, `isbn` and `eprint`, as described
> in the `biblatex` manual. However, these options are turned off as
> standard by the `phys` style. This reflects the fact that these entries
> may be present in reference databases but are not generally included
> in published  bibliographies. **Note that DOI values are printed for
> journal articles with no pages given, even if the `doi` option is
> `false`.**

So: for the first entry there are no pages given, therefore the doi is printed.

In the most recent version on Github (which is not on CTAN) also `eid` is allowed instead of `pages`, however your entry has neither.

To switch off doi printing altogether you can renew the `note+pages` bibmacro. The relevant code can be found in the [commit](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-phys/commit/1d09f20abb25def01118e9747e9f40f3d04f4c1c) that added the `pages` check.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{AlvarezJ2012,
  author = {Álvarez{-}Idaboy, J. and Galván, Marcelo and Vela, Alberto and Zicovich{-}Wilson, Claudio and Valencia, Diego and Peña, Laura and García{-}Cruz, Isidoro},
  title = {Reaction Mechanism of Hydrogenation and Direct Desulfurization Routes of Di\-ben\-zo\-thi\-o\-phene{-}Like Compounds: {A} Density Functional Theory Study},
  journal = {International Journal of Quantum Chemistry},
  volume = {112},
  date = {2012-11-15},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.24242},
  doi = {10.1002/qua.24242}
}

@article{BhadraBiswaNath2019,
  author = {Bhadra, Biswa Nath and Jhung, Sung Hwa},
  publisher = {Elsevier B.V},
  title = {Oxidative Desulfurization and Denitrogenation of Fuels Using Metal-Organic Framework-Based/-Derived Catalysts},
  journal = {Applied catalysis. B, Environmental},
  volume = {259},
  pages = {118021},
  date = {2019},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apcatb.2019.118021},
  doi = {10.1016/j.apcatb.2019.118021},
  issn = {0926-3373}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[style=phys]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\bibpagespunct}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \iftoggle{bbx:doi}
     {}
     {\clearfield{doi}}%
}
\begin{document}
\cite{AlvarezJ2012, BhadraBiswaNath2019}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Note that the [paper associated to that doi](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.24242) does actually have pages (3599-3605), so you can add those as well and solve the issue without redefinitions. Also Wiley lists only Valencia, Peña and García-Cruz as authors and not the first four that are in the citation mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yes, I looked further into the citation after reading this post. The original I posted came from my University library but when I pulled the RIS from Wiley, it came with information that is more correct. I did not realise that the lack of a page number is what was causing that. Thank you very much for the answer!